# Группировка записи в файл-текстовик с временным разделением в 3 часа

Tags: c#, файлы, filestream, .net

Всем привет, я пишу участок кода, который будет собирать инфу по логам раскидывая по папкам ../дата/файл(11:00:00- 14:00:00).txt;
у меня получился такой участок кода:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"logger");
        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            dir.Create();
        }

        var data = Console.ReadLine();

        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@$"logger/{DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString()}");
        if (!directory.Exists)
        {
            directory.Create();
        }


        File.AppendAllText(@$"logger/{DateTime.UtcNow
            .ToShortDateString()}/{DateTime.UtcNow
            .ToShortTimeString().Replace(':', '.')} - {DateTime
            .UtcNow.AddHours(3)
            .ToShortTimeString()
            .Replace(':', '.')}.txt", data + " \n", Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```

И у меня есть вопрос, как в течение 3 часов записывать в один и тот же файл? тоесть что бы не создавался ../дата/12:01:00 - 15:01:00.txt , 12:02:00 - 15:02:00.txt . Короче чтобы данные записывались не раздельно, а в один и тот же файл на промежутке 12:01:00 - 15:01:00.txt

Comment: Создать 2 метода: один пишет в один и тот же файл и второй метод пишет в новый файл, потом проверять время и вызывать первый или второй метод.

Comment: а как он поймет что в этот промежуток временной укладывается или вообще найдет его? и что бы писать в один и тот же файл, нужно же хранить его название как то и где то

Comment: Если вам помог ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы первым делом так не делал, а искал бы готовые логгеры.

Но если вы настроены серьезно такое писать руками, но в таких случаях надо нормализовать время. Например

```
string GetLogFilename(DateTime dt)
{
    var newDateTime = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, (dt.Hour / 3) * 3, 0, 0, 0, dt.Kind);
    return newDateTime.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH") + ".log";
}
```

Проверить это можно так

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.AddHours(i).ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH")} - {GetLogFilename(DateTime.Now.AddHours(i))}");
}
```

Вывод

```
2021_02_24_13 - 2021_02_24_12.log
2021_02_24_14 - 2021_02_24_12.log
2021_02_24_15 - 2021_02_24_15.log
2021_02_24_16 - 2021_02_24_15.log
2021_02_24_17 - 2021_02_24_15.log
2021_02_24_18 - 2021_02_24_18.log
2021_02_24_19 - 2021_02_24_18.log
2021_02_24_20 - 2021_02_24_18.log
2021_02_24_21 - 2021_02_24_21.log
2021_02_24_22 - 2021_02_24_21.log
2021_02_24_23 - 2021_02_24_21.log
2021_02_25_00 - 2021_02_25_00.log
2021_02_25_01 - 2021_02_25_00.log
2021_02_25_02 - 2021_02_25_00.log
2021_02_25_03 - 2021_02_25_03.log
2021_02_25_04 - 2021_02_25_03.log
2021_02_25_05 - 2021_02_25_03.log
2021_02_25_06 - 2021_02_25_06.log
2021_02_25_07 - 2021_02_25_06.log
2021_02_25_08 - 2021_02_25_06.log
2021_02_25_09 - 2021_02_25_09.log
2021_02_25_10 - 2021_02_25_09.log
2021_02_25_11 - 2021_02_25_09.log
2021_02_25_12 - 2021_02_25_12.log
2021_02_25_13 - 2021_02_25_12.log
2021_02_25_14 - 2021_02_25_12.log
2021_02_25_15 - 2021_02_25_15.log
2021_02_25_16 - 2021_02_25_15.log
2021_02_25_17 - 2021_02_25_15.log
2021_02_25_18 - 2021_02_25_18.log
```

Comment: тоесть такая функция есть в seriologe или стоковом логгере от майкрософта? без создания такого велосипеда?

Comment: @Михаил у меня нет на это ответа. Но если бы я решал вашу задачу, я бы с этого и начал. Так как логгер это не просто запись в файл, но также много чего ещё, что отсутствует у вас - тот же многопоточный доступ к файлу, отложенная запись в файл, и т.д.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за совет и ответ))