# Как сделать кастомный Seriolog.RollingInterval? или же как настроить вывод loggs в файлы определенного времени?

Tags: c#, логирование

К примеру, мне нужно сделать запись логов в файл 7.00- 10.00.txt, после 3 часов мне нужно что бы логи записывались в файлик с 10.00-13.00 часами. Как я могу это настроить? или как можно это сделать?
Или как то в ручную с помощью метода - подскажите пожалуйста. ума не приложу как это реализовать...
моя наработка :

```
loggerFactory.AddFile(@$"logger/{DateTime.UtcNow
            .ToShortDateString()}/{DateTime.UtcNow.Hour}.00 - {DateTime
            .UtcNow.AddHours(3).Hour}.00.txt", 
outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:o} {RequestId,13} [{Level:u3}] {Message} ({EventId:x8}){NewLine}{Exception} \n");
```

Она создает каждый час файлик( 8.00 - 11.00, 9.00 - 12.00), а мне бы как я описал выше(8.00-11.00.txt ; 11.00-13.00.txt).
Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248265/373567

Comment: Это не ответ на мой вопрос

Comment: Очевидно, что да, это ответ на точно такой же вопрос другого человека.

Comment: нет. мне нужно записывать данные в один файл на протяжение 3 часов. Но там только о нормализации дат описано. Такая функция есть в rollingInterval - но там только по час/год/месяц/день; поэтому я и спросил как можно это осуществить